# grails spock testing failing with 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null'

Tags: java, grails, spock

I having a method in `command class`, which use `messageSource.getMessage(...)`, as messageSource won't get injected into the `commandClass`. I use

`def messageSource = Holders.applicationContext.getBean("messageSource")` inside the `commandClass`.

My problem is when trying to write `unit test` this method,

```
@Before
void setup() {
    Holders.applicationContext.getBean("messageSource")
}

void "testFunction"() {
    //inside testFunction I am using messageSource
    given:
        //required things
    when:
        //call the function
    then:
        //assert
}
```

after testing this function, I getting the error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ServletContext must not be null
at grails.util.Holders.getApplicationContext(Holders.java:80)`

Can someone suggest on how to resolve this one.

**Update**

```
@Validateable
class commandClass {
    //required fields and constraints
    def formatData(List<commandClass> commandObjs) {
        StringBuilder validationErrors
        commandObjs.each {commandObj->
            validationErrors = new StringBuilder()
            if(commandObj.hasErrors()) {
                commandObj.errors.allErrors.each {it ->
                    validationErrors.append(messageSource.getMessage(it, null)).append('\n')
                }
            }
            commandObj.metaClass.validationErrors = validationErrors
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please provide the Command class in the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer

```
void setup() {
    mockApplicationContext()
}

def static mockApplicationContext() {
    GrailsUnitTestMixin.initGrailsApplication()
    Holders.grailsApplication = GrailsUnitTestMixin.grailsApplication
    Holders.metaClass.'static'.getApplicationContext = { ->
        return GrailsUnitTestMixin.applicationContext
    }
    Holders.metaClass.applicationContext.getBean = { bean ->
        return GrailsUnitTestMixin.messageSource
    }
}
```

I 'll update more about the answer later

Answer (score 2):

**============UPDATED ANSWER========================**

Right now I am using grails 2.4.2.

Here you do not need to use `Holders.applicationContext.getBean("messageSource")` to get messageSource, it will be automatically injected.

So the example of the Command object:

```
@Validateable
class Test {
    def messageSource
    String aa

    static constraints = {
    aa blank:false, validator: {val, obj ->
            println obj.messageSource.getMessage("default.paginate.prev",null,LocaleContextHolder.locale)
            ...
        }
    ...
```

The example of the test :

```
void "test for valid data"() {
    when:
    def test = new Test(aa:'hello')
    def messageSource = Mock(MessageSource)
    test.messageSource = messageSource
    then:
    test.validate()
}
```

Instead of Mock, you can also use mockFor.

**=========OLD ANSWER============**

Instead of directly using `messageSource` in `Command object`, you can use `service` there and wrap the `messageSource` by the `service`.

The example of the service :

```
class I18nMessageService {
    MessageSource messageSource

    def getMessage(String code, Object[] args=null) {
        messageSource.getMessage(code,args,LocaleContextHolder.locale)
    }
}
```

The example of the Command object :

```
@Validateable
class Test {
    def i18nMessageService
    String aa

    static constraints = {
        aa blank:false, validator: {val, obj ->
            println obj.i18nMessageService.getMessage("default.paginate.next")
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The i18nMessageService is automatically injected to the Test command object while running app.

For test, i18nMessageService should be mocked and injected manually.

The example of the test :

```
void "test for valid data"() {
    when:
    def test = new Test(aa:'hello')
    def i18nMessageServiceMock = mockFor(I18nMessageService)
    i18nMessageServiceMock.demand.getMessage {'message you wanted'}
    test.i18nMessageService = i18nMessageServiceMock.createMock()
    then:
    test.validate()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, We can directly use `MessageSource`, inside the command class only right?

Comment: Which version of grails do you use?

Comment: `grails 2.3.8` version

Comment: Ok thnk you, let me try

Comment: I am also checking in 2.3.8 version.

Comment: What you thinking about this link http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-access-messagesource-in-bean-messagesourceaware/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63573/discussion-between-suganthan-and-ramsharan).

Comment: Hi, with updated code I getting java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getMessage() on null object, means MessageSource is not injected

Comment: This is not the code `obj.i18nMessageService.getMessage("default.paginate.next")`, I have to call the `service method` inside another method

Comment: I have edited the answer. You need to call `obj.messageSource.getMessage` to get message

Comment: No Ram it is not working. As I said, I need to call whatever things inside 'formatData' method

Comment: What's giving you problem?

Comment: I think I solved the issue, within sometime I 'll post the code

Comment: Great. Ok please post it.

Comment: Give me sometime. I am working on it, anyway thanks for continous support

Comment: see my answer, I posted my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Grails 3, you just to add the annotation

```
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
```

before your class definition.

This will inject a variable called applicationContext in your unit test.